# 10 yr old checking account in USA closed automatically by the bank due to no activity, can I recover the money?

Tags: united-states, bank-account

I used to have a checking account in a US bank (Suntrust). I've long ago stopped using it because I moved out of the country. There was no activity on the  account for 10 years, and the bank closed the account several months ago. There was still some money left in there. Is it possible to recover it?

Comment: How much money was left in the account when it was closed?  As far as you know, did the bank apply any dormant-account fees when it closed the account?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can probably recover it by checking with the unclaimed property division of the state where you opened the account.

See [The Office of the Comptroller of the Currency](http://www.helpwithmybank.gov/faqs/banking_inactive.html) website for more information.

Comment: Act quickly... Many states treat abandoned property as a revenue stream, some states like Arizona contract out the claims process and provide incentives for NOT paying people!

Comment: You might be able to recover it, however, if there was any way for the bank to drain your account by way of monthly fee, then almost certainly your account has sublimated.

Comment: These are all reasons for my use of "probably". Florida owes me 350 bucks. I've tried to get it and have given up.

Comment: how much money are we talking about?